# Is Operator a Compact Operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

So I have this linear operator:
$$ A : C_{[0,1]} \rightarrow C_{[0,1]}: (Ax)(t) = \int_{0}^{1}(ts + t^2s^2)x(s)ds $$
And I need to check if it is a compact one. According to Arzela-Ascoli theorem, I should check if $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ is precompact in $C_{[0,1]}$:

1)Is $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ uniformly bounded?

I should evaluate $|y(t)|$ such that $y \in\operatorname{Im}(A) $: $$ |y(t)| = \int_{0}^{1}(ts + t^2s^2)x(s)ds \le \left\| x \right\| \int_{0}^{1}(ts + t^2s^2)ds \le \left\| x \right\| \frac{3t+2t^2}{6} \le \left\| x \right\|$$
At this place I stopped. What should I do next? Or maybe I made a mistake somewhere?

2)Is $
\operatorname{Im}(A)$ equicontinuous?

By definition, $$ \forall y \in \operatorname{Im}(A): \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists\delta: \forall t_1,t_2 : |t_1 - t_2 | < \delta \Rightarrow |y(t_1) - y(t_2) | < \epsilon  $$
Thus, I do next $$ |\int_{0}^{1}(t_1s + t_1^2s^2)x(s)ds - \int_{0}^{1}(t_2s + t_2^2s^2)x(s)ds|  = |\int_{0}^{1}((t_1-t_2)s + (t_1^2-t_2^2)s^2)x(s)ds| < \delta\left\| x \right\| \int_0^1s+(t_1 + t_2)s^2ds = \delta \left\| x \right\| \frac{3 + 2(t_1+t_2)}{6} $$
And at this point I also stopped and have no clue what I should do next. 

Hope for the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be the closed unit ball (for the uniform norm) of $C[0,1]$. Then in order to establish uniform boundedness, it suffices to bound $\lVert x\rVert$ by one to see that all the elements of $\operatorname{Im}(B)$ have norm smaller than one.

For equicontinuity, you can continue the bound by writing 
$$
\left\| x \right\| \frac{3 + 2(t_1+t_2)}{6}\leqslant  \frac{3 + 2(t_1+t_2)}{6}\leqslant 7/6,
$$
since $t_1,t_2\leqslant 1$.

An alternative way to show compactness is that $(Ax)(t)=f_1(x)t+f_2(x)t^2$ where $f_1,f_2$ are linear continuous functionals on $C[0,1]$. Hence if $(x_n)$ is a sequence of elements of $B$, extract from $(f_1(x_n))$ a bounded subsequence $(f_1(x_{n_k}))$, and 
a further subsequence from $(f_2(x_{n_k}))$ to get a norm-convergent subsequence of $\left(Bx_n\right)$.

Comment: Oh, my bad, $A$ is an operator we work with, I named it as $L$ for some reason, but actually I used to name it as $A$. Fixed it. 

Can I say that $ \left\| x \right\| \le \sup_{x \in C_{[0,1]}} \left\| x \right\| $, and therefore the image of the operator is uniformly bounded?
Can you explain, please, why you eradicated $\left\| x \right\| $ at "equicontinuity part"? I feel it's not so clear for me.

Comment: Actually you have to work with the image of the unit ball. The range of $A$ is vector space hence it would be unbounded.

Comment: Do you mean I need to take the unit ball in $C_{[0,1]}$ and check if its image is precompact, right?

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you, that actually solves everything, as far as $\left\| x \right\| \le 1 $, I can evaluate everything I need.